# Do I need to include only whole seasons in training/test sets of time series?

Tags: time-series

I have a daily time series, with weekly seasonality, but it starts and ends in the middle of the week (Wed/Thu, during the season peak).

I have two questions:

1. Should I drop the first and last partial weeks from the data before modelling?
2. When splitting into training and test sets, should I also make sure to include only whole seasons in each set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it is probably better to use and keep all data. Repeated-measures methods as implemented in functions like `lmer` from **`R`** package **`lme4`**, and `gam` and `s` from **`mgcv`** do not require higher-level units to have the same number of lower-level units.
2. Yes. Cross-validated accuracy measures are likely less optimistic when you sample at the higher than at the lower level.

Comment: Thank you @Marjolein.

Comment: @Kazumi You are welcome